# Django : "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I'm using django rest framework. These are my settings for REST FRAMEWORK,

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly',
    )
    # 'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
    #     'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    # ),
}
```

When I post to a simple endpoint, I get the following error,

```
{
    "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."
}
```

What am I doing wrong here. Any help appreciated.

Comment: did you added auth credentials to your POST request ?

Comment: something similar to `request.post(url,headers,data)` or `request.post(url,auth,data)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing the `POST` request while your default permission class ([IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#isauthenticatedorreadonly)) is set to allow only unauthorized requests for `GET`, `HEAD` and `OPTIONS`

Comment: @MelissaStewart you cannot post to it until you change permissions for following endpoint, self explanatory documentation can be found here.
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#setting-the-permission-policy